# d3s different colours for category links

Tags: javascript

I want to change the color of the different categories from this example

https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/7607999

As you can see, there are categories, between those are more spaces. 
Maybe someone could solve this problem!

Comment: This isn't a coding service.  Show us what you've tried and what the results are.

Comment: sorry, my version looks like this one http://plnkr.co/edit/I90Z7pY7slvud37oynlo?p=preview